# Can't enter a variable in DOS

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, user-input, dos

I'm trying to run a batch file in vDOS (DOS emulator), where I want the user to input two variables. Every time I run the file, it doesn't let me enter the variables.

```
SET /P in=Input:
SET /P out=Output:
```

What I expected to happen was that It'd let me enter the input for the variables. 
Instead, it executes both of the commands as they are (without letting me enter the input).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Windows cmd and MS-DOS are very different things](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386) and one of the differences is the `set` command. In MS-DOS the only form of set is `set variable=value`. There are neither `set /A`, `set "variable=value"` nor `set /P`.

`set /P` is a feature of Windows NT's cmd.exe. In DOS you must use 3<sup>rd</sup> party software to get user input and store in a variable. Here are some solutions

- [`SENVAR.COM`](http://www.robholland.com/downloads/Documents/BatchFiles/Senvar.html)

  ```bat
  SENVAR INPUT Input string:
  ```
- [`EDITVAR` and `CHOOSE`](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/EditVar.shtml)

  ```bat
  editvar -p "Input string: " INPUT
  ```
- [FC.COM](https://web.archive.org/web/20190207160424/http://www.infionline.net/%7Ewtnewton/batch/batguide.html)

  ```bat
    @echo off
    :: based on batch from PC Magazine June 27, 1995 page 248
    :: this version puts temps in C:\DOS dir and shortens var names
    :: User input is returned in variable STR
    :input
    > C:\DOS\en#er.bat fc con nul /lb1 /n|date|find "    1:  "
    > C:\DOS\enter.bat echo set str=
    >>C:\DOS\enter.bat echo :loop
    >>C:\DOS\enter.bat echo if not '%%str%%==' set str=%%str%% %%5
    >>C:\DOS\enter.bat echo if '%%str%%==' set str=%%5
    >>C:\DOS\enter.bat echo shift
    >>C:\DOS\enter.bat echo if not '%%5==' goto loop
    call en#er.bat
    del C:\DOS\enter.bat
    del C:\DOS\en#er.bat
  ```
- [ANSI.SYS](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/userinput.php#DOS)

  ```bat
    @ECHO OFF

    REM * Ask for USeR INPUT and store it in variable USRINPUT
    REM * Assumes ANSI.SYS is loaded
    REM * Written by Rob van der Woude

    SET USRINPUT=

    REM * Turn on ANSI key translation (translate Enter
    REM * key to F6+Enter sequence) and ask for input:
    ECHO ←[13;0;64;13pEnter one word only . . .

    REM * Copy entered text to temporary file:
    COPY CON %TEMP%.\~USRINP.TMP

    REM * Turn off ANSI key translation and clear irrelevant screen output:
    ECHO ←[13;13p←[3A←[K←[1B←[K←[1B←[K←[2A

    REM * Add empty line to temporary file. The empty line
    REM * will be used to stop DATE asking for new date.
    ECHO.>> %TEMP%.\~USRINP.TMP
    ECHO.>> %TEMP%.\~USRINP.TMP


    REM * Create a temporary batch file that will store the
    REM * entered text into the environment variable USRINPUT:
    TYPE %TEMP%.\~USRINP.TMP | DATE | FIND "):" > %TEMP%.\~USRINP.BAT

    REM * Create more temporary batch files. Add
    REM * more command line parameters if necessary,
    REM * as in: ECHO SET USRINPUT=%%3 %%4 %%5 %%6 %%7 %%8 %%9>CURRENT.BAT
    ECHO SET USRINPUT=%%3>CURRENT.BAT

    REM * VOER.BAT and TYP.BAT are replacements for CURRENT.BAT for Dutch
    REM * DOS versions; add your own language versions if necessary:
    ECHO SET USRINPUT=%%6>VOER.BAT
    ECHO SET USRINPUT=%%4>TYP.BAT

    REM * This temporary batch file now sets the variable USRINPUT:
    CALL %TEMP%.\~USRINP.BAT

    REM * Display the result:
    ECHO You typed: ←[1m%USRINPUT%&larr;[0m
    ECHO.
    PAUSE

    REM * Finally, clean up the mess of temporary files:
    FOR %%A IN (%TEMP%.\~USRINP.BAT %TEMP%.\~USRINP.TMP VOER.BAT TYP.BAT CURRENT.BAT) DO DEL %%A
  ```

The ← is the [escape character (27h)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esc_key)

In case you just want to get simple answers like Y/N then `CHOICE.COM` is designed for that purpose

See also

- [MS-DOS 6.22 Batch File User Input to Environment Variable](https://alt.msdos.batch.narkive.com/BiFld4r6/ms-dos-6-22-batch-file-user-input-to-environment-variable)
- [Prompt for variable in DOS 7.1](https://msfn.org/board/topic/174005-prompt-for-variable-in-dos-71/)

Answer (score 1):

`/P` didn't get introduced until Windows 2000 or NT.  Legacy MS-DOS or equivalent won't have it.  https://www.computerhope.com/sethlp.htm